# JUnit for testing the reversion of a Singly Linked List

Tags: java, testing, junit, linked-list, reverse

I need to write JUnits in order to test the **reverse** method of a singly linked list. This is the code I have for the link list

```
 class ReversedLinkedList { 

   static Node head; 

   static class Node { 

    int data; 
    Node next; 

    Node(int d) { 
        data = d; 
        next = null; 
     } 
  } 

/* Function to reverse the linked list */
Node reverse(Node node) { 
    Node prev = null; 
    Node current = node; 
    Node next = null; 
    while (current != null) { 
        next = current.next; 
        current.next = prev; 
        prev = current; 
        current = next; 
    } 
    node = prev; 
    return node; 
  } 

  // prints content of double linked list 
  void printList(Node node) { 
    while (node != null) { 
        System.out.print(node.data + " "); 
        node = node.next; 
    } 
  } 

    public static void run(ReverseLinkedList list, Node head) {
   head = list.reverse(head);
   list.printList(head);
   }
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    ReverseLinkedList list = new ReverseLinkedList(); 
    list.head = new Node(85); 
    list.head.next = new Node(15); 
    list.head.next.next = new Node(4); 
    list.head.next.next.next = new Node(20);
    run(list, head);
    }
  }
```

Now I want to make JUnits in order to test the **reverse** method, but I I am not sure how I should do it. Should I refactor the code somehow to achieve this? So far, this is what is in my test class:

```
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

 import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

 import ReverseLinkedList.Node;

class ReverseLinkedListTest {

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@Test
void testReversion() {
    ReverseLinkedList list = new ReverseLinkedList(); 
    list.head = new Node(85); 
    list.head.next = new Node(15); 
    list.head.next.next = new Node(4); 
    list.head.next.next.next = new Node(20); 

} }
```

But my test class does not even compile, I get the following error:

```
    Multiple markers at this line
   - Node cannot be resolved to a type
   - The static field ReverseLinkedList.head should be accessed in a 
     static way
```

Comment: The first error indicates that you must use `ReverseLinkedList.Node` instead of just `Node` to refer to the type Node, or to add a *static* import for this class. The second shows that the `head` of a list is statis, and that you access it as if it was an instance field. The test is actually right in this case: it makes no sense for all the linked list to share a unique head node.

Comment: The first one means you're missing an import.  The second one is a warning that `head` is static and you're calling it in a non-static way.

Comment: Typo in the above comment. It must be `LinkedList.Node`.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks this worked. now I am doing                                               
          String output = "20 4 15 85";
        assertEquals(output, list.run(list, list.head));   and I get the error Multiple markers at this line
 - The static method run(ReverseLinkedList, ReverseLinkedList.Node) from the type ReverseLinkedList should be accessed in a 
  static way
 - The method assertEquals(Object, Object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, void)
 - The static field ReverseLinkedList.head should be accessed in a static way. Do you understand why?

Comment: You need to learn what static means and when to use it. You seem to randomly use it without understanding: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html. The second message is slf-explanatory. Have you *carefully* read it? What don't you understand? Explain what you think it means.